# Google CDN - From Australia

Tags: amp-html

We have a challenge when it comes to optimizing the speed of our AMP site.

For example - this page:

https://www.adorebeauty.com.au/skin-care.html?amp=1

1) Local Pops

We are using the google CDN to load all the AMP js however in Australia we are seeing slow loading times for the js.

Looking further, It looks like(at least on my machine) that the files are being served from 216.58.220.97 which is from Washington state USA. Does anyone know if there are, or plans to have additional pops that are closer to Australia.

2) Deferred Loading

Is there any way at all to defer loading of any scripts until after the page load event?

Apologies for the basic question, this is still bleeding edge for us and we are trying to make this experience as fast as possible!

Comment: I believe moving the JS to the footer rather than the header results in it being loaded last, but of course this might break something on your page!

Comment: Hey @dave , ill give that a crack mate - lets see if its possible one thing concerns me from here - https://www.ampproject.org/docs/reference/spec  contain a <script async src="https://cdn.ampproject.org/v0.js"></script> tag inside their head tag.

Answer (score 0):

The AMP JS should be served from a local server. Let me know if you persist to seeing it served from the US.

There are a few simple things you can do to optimize your page load time:

- Make v0.js the first script you detect.
- Move all the script tags above the custom style tag.

The latter is very impactful as it will start the download while the style tag is still being streamed over the network.

Comment: Thanks @malte-ubi - ill take a look now mate and get back to you